# How to install py-yajl through setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, yajl

I want to install py-yajl through setup.py like this.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

requires = [
    'yajl',
]

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=requires,
    tests_require=requires,
    ...
)
```

But this setup.py has some errors.

```
>>> Creating a symlink for compilationg: includes/yajl -> yajl/src/api
error: SandboxViolation: symlink('../yajl/src/api', 'includes/yajl') {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

I know I can install yajl using pip.
If some config could be changed by setup.py to use pip, I will install yajl but I don't know how to do it.

Does someone have a good idea?